# Card reader does not seem to work

Tags: thinkpad, sd-card, card-reader

My laptop lenovo W520 has this issue.

I have the following output on the commands used here

```
nishant@nishant-ThinkPad-W520:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 17ef:1003 Lenovo Integrated Smart Card Reader
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b217 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Lenovo Integrated Camera (0.3MP)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:217f Broadcom Corp. BCM2045B (BDC-2.1)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

---

```
$ sudo lsblk -f
NAME   FSTYPE  LABEL UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
loop0  squashf                                            /snap/gnome-characters
loop1  squashf                                            /snap/vscode/37
loop2  squashf                                            /snap/gnome-logs/25
loop3  squashf                                            /snap/gnome-system-mon
loop4  squashf                                            /snap/gnome-calculator
loop5  squashf                                            /snap/core/4486
loop6  squashf                                            /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/
sda                                                       
└─sda1 ext4          7889ad88-06a3-4957-a85f-2da6f9cb2b1e /
sr0
```

---

```
$ sudo dmesg | tail -n 50
[    5.593030] uvcvideo 1-1.6:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!
[    5.593104] input: Integrated Camera: Integrated C as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.0/input/input10
[    5.593164] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[    5.593164] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[    5.623082] kvm: disabled by bios
[    5.634353] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
[    5.681271] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[    5.697779] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain package
[    5.697781] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain core
[    5.697782] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain uncore
[    5.697786] intel_rapl: RAPL package 0 domain package locked by BIOS
[    5.704438] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    5.721084] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0: CX20590: BIOS auto-probing.
[    5.721550] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for CX20590: line_outs=1 (0x1f/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[    5.721551] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    5.721552] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=2 (0x1c/0x19/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    5.721553] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    5.721554] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[    5.721556] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:      Internal Mic=0x23
[    5.721557] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x1b
[    5.721558] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:      Dock Mic=0x1a
[    5.722863] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0: Enable sync_write for stable communication
[    5.736187] input: HDA Intel PCH Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input11
[    5.736231] input: HDA Intel PCH Dock Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input12
[    5.736273] input: HDA Intel PCH Dock Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input13
[    5.736312] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input14
[    6.372607] random: crng init done
[    7.148238] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    7.148241] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    7.148252] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    7.389185] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s25: link is not ready
[    7.604341] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s25: link is not ready
[    7.607926] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[    7.613507] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Radio type=0x0-0x3-0x1
[    7.856254] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Radio type=0x0-0x3-0x1
[    7.958132] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[    8.100499] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[    9.684538] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    9.684544] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    9.684548] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   10.695673] rfkill: input handler disabled
[   11.273094] wlp3s0: authenticate with 9c:d6:43:d7:62:ba
[   11.274999] wlp3s0: send auth to 9c:d6:43:d7:62:ba (try 1/3)
[   11.276728] wlp3s0: authenticated
[   11.276895] wlp3s0: waiting for beacon from 9c:d6:43:d7:62:ba
[   11.344032] wlp3s0: associate with 9c:d6:43:d7:62:ba (try 1/3)
[   11.348210] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from 9c:d6:43:d7:62:ba (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
[   11.360030] wlp3s0: associated
[   11.376209] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
[   16.320971] thinkpad_acpi: EC reports that Thermal Table has changed
```

How do I trouble shoot this one...? :/

Answer (score 0):

How do you trouble shoot *which one*?  Your laptop has *which* issue?  Your non-question talks about a "card reader" in the title and nothing else.  The Thinkpad W520 is listed with the following peripherals:

```
4-in-1 Media Card Reader slot
One ExpressCard slot
One SmartCard slot
```

You write about "lsusb" but that *only* is relevant regarding the SmartCard reader (which reads out the data from the chip on credit cards and their ilk).

Using a SmartCard reader requires specific software and only some sorts of smart chard are supported under GNU/Linux.  Listing the block devices makes me suspect very much that you are not actually talking about the SmartCard reader but are more likely interested in the 4-in-1 media card reader (which would be about SD cards and their ilk).

However, information about that reader would only appear using

lspci

or similar since at least the internal reader is not usually connected via USB but through a PCI express lane.

So what are you actually trying to do using which reader and which media and what are the symptoms that make you think something is wrong?